# Facing issue while creating Regular expression in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Please help me with building regular expression for the below response sequence

I have defined a variable PlanName = prod-p1 in testplan.

Response:

```
projectmanagement.plan.Plan%3A2992173879&amp;u8=1\" ext:qtip=\"prod-p1\">prod-p1<\/a>
```

Regular Expression build is:

```
ptc.projectmanagement.plan.Plan\%3A([^"]+)&amp\;u8=1\\" ext:qtip\=\\"${PlanName}\\">${PlanName}\<\\
```

Currently I am getting below error in Jmeter

```
jmeter.extractor.RegexExtractor: Error in pattern: ptc.projectmanagement.plan.Plan\%3A(.+?)\&amp\;u8=1\" ext:qtip\=\"prod-p1\">prod-p1\<\
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `\` symbols with another backslash so amend your regular expression to look like:

```
projectmanagement.plan.Plan%3(.+?)&u8=1\\" ext:qtip=\\"prod-p1\\">prod-p1</a>
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regex Demo]

References:

- [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)
- [JMeter Regular Expressions: Meta Characters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Apologies for the trouble. The RegEX that was posted by me is working. 

Actually issue is arising when i am trying to replace prod-p1 with a variable name that is defined at test plan. 


So RegEx is 
ptc.projectmanagement.plan.Plan\%3A([^"]+)&amp\;u8=1\\" ext:qtip\=\\"${PlanName}\\">${PlanName}\<\\

I have defined PlanName in testplan as prod-p1

Variable is getting replaces in regular expresion but i am getting below error

jmeter.extractor.RegexExtractor: Error in pattern: ptc.projectmanagement.plan.Plan\%3A(.+?)\&amp\;u8=1\" ext:qtip\=\"prod-p1\">prod-p1\<\

Comment: Please refer updated question. Thanks and apologies once again

Answer (score 0):

Check the below regular expression and output:-

```
projectmanagement.plan.Plan%3A(.+?)&u8=1\\" ext:qtip=\\"prod-p1\\">prod-p1</a>
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

@Suraj

Use the following Regular Expression

```
projectmanagement\.plan\.Plan%3A(.+?)&u8=1\\" ext
```

In your response there are . and \ tokens , To match those characters append a backslash () so that JMeter matches the character . or \ literally.

[image]

For more information

[JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

[Extracting Variables in Jmeter](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)

You can use [this website](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expressions